# Virtual host for specific folder not entire domain?

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am using XAMPP on localhost for some dev work (this will only be used for dev and not go into production) and I have it set at the moment that if I try and one go to the dev server (dev.example.com) it will look for it on the machine instead of the internet. However it is redirecting everything going to dev.example.com to the localhost. I only need it to do that for one of the folders. If I go to http://dev.example.com/website1 it should only look for the website1 on the localhost and if I try go to http://dev.example.com/website2 it will look for that on the actual webserver and not my localhost but at the moment it is looking for both on localhost.

In the hosts file I changed dev.example.com to point to 127.0.0.1 and this is what I have in the httdp.vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\website1"
    ServerName http://dev.example.com
    <Directory "C:\xammp\htdocs\website1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I know part of the issue is because I specified in the localhost to look for dev.example.com at 127.0.0.1 but I wasn't able to make the virtual host work any other way and I am unsure how else to make this work (if at all)

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your `httdp.vhosts.conf`

Try above code in `httdp.vhosts.conf` file:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.example.com
 DocumentRoot "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\website1"
 ServerName dev.example.com
 ErrorLog "logs/dev.example.com-error.log"
 CustomLog "logs/dev.example.com-access.log" common
       <Directory "C:\xammp\htdocs\website1">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
       </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Then, add `127.0.0.1       dev.example.com` in `hosts` file.

Comment: and that will let me go to dev.example.com/website2 on the actual website and not on my localhost?